# How to send json data in websocket feed

Tags: c#, websocket

I am using the WebSocketSharp client library to get data from a feed. The code in winform application is :

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com"))
{
   ws.Connect();

   string json = "{\"type\": \"subscribe\",  \"product_ids\": [\"BTC-USD\"]}";
   ws.Send(json);                
}
```

But when I send i get error "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."

can anyone please suggest sample code on how can I send data to that address and receive the response?

Comment: try with an @ symbol: string json = @"{\"type\": \"subscribe\",  \"product_ids\": [\"BTC-USD\"]}";

Comment: still not working

Comment: right, also exchange the \ with another " like this: string json = @"{""type"": ""subscribe"",  ""product_ids"": [""BTC-USD""]}";

Answer (score 1):

On client side you could use:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Buffer);
```

Then in server/receiver side, you just use:

```
var unmixedAudioBuffer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type'>(args.Data);
```